# angular2-cli when change route assets folder css or js not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-cli

- So This is a Angular 2-cli project and Here's the Problem
  my third party css and js are in assets folder 
  and all assets css and js link to index page 
  but when i change the route of css and js, they don't load properly...
  and when hard reload(press enter in url) the current route css and js file loads up properly in one page but again when i change route and go to the other page the problem still persists.
  please help me. what i can i do 
  **

> Here's The Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Some Title</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/><!-- bootstrap grid -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/><!-- bootstrap theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/color-red.css"/><!-- default template color styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/retina.css"/><!-- retina ready styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/animate.css"/><!-- animation for content -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/colors-header.css"/><!-- header styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/odometer.min.css"><!-- Number counter -->
  <!-- Magnific pop up plugin css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/magnific-popup.css"/>
  <!-- Font icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/><!-- Fontawesome icons css -->
  <!-- Google Web fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,700%7CPlayfair+Display:400,700&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- Hamburger menu list -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/jquery.fatNav.min.css">
  <!-- Main stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/style.css"/><!-- template styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/responsive.css"/><!-- responsive styles -->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root> Loading.....</app-root>

  <div class="loading">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  </div>

  <script src="/src/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="/src/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- .bootstrap script -->
  <script src="/src/assets/js/jquery.scripts.min.js"></script><!-- modernizr -->

  <script src="/src/assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery isotope -->
  <script src="/src/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery isotope -->
  <script src="/src/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script> <!-- Magnific pop up lightbox -->

  <script src="/src/assets/odometer/odometer.min.js"></script><!-- Odometer -->
  <script src="/src/assets/js/jquery-retina.js"></script><!-- retina -->
  <script src="/src/assets/js/jquery.fatNav.js"></script><!-- retina -->
  <script src="/src/assets/js/volcanno.include.js"></script><!-- custom js functions -->

  <script>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      'use strict';
      VolcannoInclude.contactFormAjax('newsletter');
      $.fatNav();
      jQuery(".number-counter-container").waypoint(function () {
        jQuery(".timer-number").each(function () {
          var v = jQuery(this).data("to");
          var o = new Odometer({
            el: this,
            value: 0,
            duration: 15000
          });
          o.render();
          setInterval(function () {
            o.update(v);
          });
        });

      },{
        offset: "80%",
        triggerOnce: true
      });

      // OPEN PORTFOLIO LIGHTBOX GALLERY
      $('.portfolio-item-hover-button').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
          enabled: true
        }
      });
    });
    /* ]]> */
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### **

[Here's The Snap Of the Directory Structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0oNE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the angular-cli.json provided by Angular CLI to load the css files instad of loading them in your index.html. Same goes for your js files.

Comment: i have tried css and js link put in angular-cli.json bu problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

it`s better to use webpack with loaders plugin to inject your js and css codes to the page. webpack will do it automatically, you just need to add 'style-loader' and 'css-loader' to inject css files and external js files will import by using for example :

```
import '../js/lib.js'
```

but for external js files you need to add ts file for typescript compiler to know them.

to loading css style you have to add this in you appComponent.ts

```
import '../assets/style.css'
```